# Help me understand the viewport render pipeline with cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, development, source-code

I am trying to understand the pipeline that creates a rendered image in the viewport with cycles from start to finish in the blender/cycles source code.

A little bit of context (Skip if not interested):

> A colleague of mine and myself are trying to develop a derivate of blender in which the viewport isn't fully rerendered every time any change to the scene is made when using cycles as the viewport renderer.
>  Instead we want to achieve a logic that detects the parts of the view that where most affected by changes and only rerenders those. The goal here is to achieve a less interrupted workflow for artists.
>  If you have any suggestions how we can achieve this or any material on that matter, pls kindly forward it to me if you can.

So far, I could identify the following steps in the code:

- draw_manager.c : DRW_draw_view ->
- draw_manager.c : DRW_draw_render_loop_ex (render Loop for external render engines?) ->
- draw_manager.c : drw_engines_init ->
- external_engine.c : external_engine_init (Cycles is an external render engine?) ->
- draw_manager.c : drw_engines_draw_scene ->
- external_engine.c : external_draw_scene ->
- external_engine.c : external_draw_scene_do

These steps seem to appear every time a view is updated by any sort of event and they happen independently of the main window loop started in blenders main function in creator.c.

Afterwards, if I use the debugger to jump further into the code, I get directed through a bunch of RNA related classes which I can't completely wrap my head around. I can't seem to find the point where the blender code finally calls the cycles code.

What I do know is that eventually I end up at the draw function in the blender_session.cpp of the cycles code.

It would be greatly apprecheated if someone could help me understand the code that happens inbetween these two parts. Where exactly is the point where the blender code calls the cycles code?

English isn't my native language, so please forgive any mistakes i might have made in this question. I thank all of you in advance and hope my question is formulated understandably enough to be answered.